# Is there a way to specify type converters for graphene input types?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

Lets say I have the following GraphQL schema written in graphene,

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    dummy_query = graphene.Field(String, name=graphene.String(required=True))

    def resolve_dummy_query(self, info, name):
        print(type(name))
        return None
```

I am using Flask to host this API,

```py
view_func = GraphQLView.as_view('graphql',
                                schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query),
                                graphiql=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/graphql', view_func=view_func)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
```

The following is the query I'm providing using GraphiQL

```
{
    dummyQuery(name: "My name")
}
```

When the resolve function is getting executed, the type of `name` is being shown as `unicode`.

Is there a way to specify a type converter in the schema definition so that this gets converted to `str` when it is in the resolve function?

Note:

- I'm using python 2.7
- I can't manually convert it to `str` everytime because the application is large and there are many input types which I would like to convert to other types.